# VBA Form: can't get any button,input in center with math

Tags: excel, vba, user-interface

I'm trying to center a button in my form.

Width form: 250

With button: 200

Tried left: 25

So... the button should be centered. But it isn't. (don't have enough reputation to post a screenshot)

I tried to center it relative to a full-with text. It put the left value of 20. But why?

Comment: `CommandButton1.Left = (Me.InsideWidth - CommandButton1.Width) / 2`

Comment: @Siddharth Rout thank you! I debugged it and the inside with is 237,75. This tip helped me!

Comment: BTW you know you can center the button in the form in design time? VBA Menu: `Format|Center In Form`

Comment: Yes, I know this. But usually I calculate it. If you design per hand, you get easily into weird numbers. I had also could use this function, but I just wanted to know why it didn't work for me :D